# Using pointInside:withEvent: for different gestures

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have two view `A` and `B`. `B` is subview of `A`. I want to monitor double tap actions in `A`, in this case, I will move `B` to tap position.

Now, I want to make that part of codes inside `B`, which will avoid coding in `A`.

So I added a double tap gesture recogniser in `B`, and I have overwritten the `-pointInside:withEvent:` in `B`, so it can react to double tap action outside `B`'s frame.

However, I still want other gestures (including single tap) work on `A`, so I came up with two different ways on how to do this:

1. Recognize inside `pointInside:`, and for single taps, return `NO`, for double tap∫, return `YES`, however, seems there is no way to do this.
2. Always return YES for `pointInside:`, and capture both single taps and double tap gestures. For single tap gestures, send it to A to handle, however, still not find a way for this.

Anyone can help me one this? Or tell If I am looking in a wrong direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach *could* work, but it's very messy, simply because, the `pointInside:withEvent:` is a very primitive call.

When you double tap on a view, you'll receive multiple `hitTest:withEvent:` method calls (which, in turn, calls to `pointInisde:withEvent:`), meaning that you'd have to do some hard work by using a time offset to measure whenever two taps occur one after the other.

How many calls does it get? As many as it can, every milisecond your finger rests on the screen, this method will get carpet-bombed by method calls. It's simply not wise to overload it for what you intend to do.

Simply put, gestures recognizers are very convenient objects that encapsulate all the complexities of having to deal with real time `UITouch` by yourself.

As a solution that keeps the code relatively clean, you could add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `A`and then hand the selector for `B` to handle, you can even do this in interface builder, or through code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:B action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[A addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

(`A` and `B` being your views)

Comment: It works except that there is no view in B to eat the event, say, a uiwebview may handle the long press, double tap etc... I finally overwrite sendevent and do some notification handler.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. B is also a view, so it should be able to handle events